# how can possible only audio calling using quickblox in android?

Tags: android, quickblox-android

I am using this code for audio calling and start call but how can another user receive incoming call ? please check this Screenshot [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9VBA.png)

```
 List<Integer> opponents = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            opponents.add(Integer.valueOf(quickBlox_Id)); //12345 - QBUser ID
            Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
            userInfo.put("key", quickBlox_Id);
            QBRTCSession session =QBRTCClient.getInstance(this).createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponents, QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_AUDIO);
            session.startCall(userInfo);
```

Comment: have you used sample code of quickblox ?

Comment: install apk on your two devices login or register with two user and start calling

Comment: Already two user register in two different devices and also be login in chat services and start call also be call but another user does not get  incoming call  so how can i receiving incoming audio call  ?

Comment: can you send screenshot of your app

Comment: i am add Link in my post please check this.

Comment: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc have you used this code ?

Comment: I am refer official tutorial and right now i am not use the above link code.

Comment: use this code its quickblox sample

Answer (score -1):

Is the user ID of the another user is correct?

Try to call him with creating another account. I think users must not use same credentials to call each other. Please use different credentials and test again. It might work.